# found xmin X from before relfrozenxid Y during vacuum

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

The vacuum of two pg_catalog tables runs into the following error and stops there.

> found xmin X from before relfrozenxid Y during vacuum

I could find a lot of discussions about this problem but solutions are hard to find. Is there any solution for this problem other then restoring the database from a backup?

postgresql 9.3.22 (I know it is old, the server is being phased out but needs to continue working for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be in luck.

The [last but one point release for 9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/release-9-3-24.html) has this change:

> - Ensure that updates to the `relfrozenxid` and `relminmxid` values for "nailed" system catalogs are processed in a timely fashion (Andres Freund)
>
>   Overoptimistic caching rules could prevent these updates from being seen by other sessions, leading to spurious errors and/or data corruption. The problem was significantly worse for shared catalogs, such as `pg_authid`, because the stale cache data could persist into new sessions as well as existing ones.

See the [discussion on the -hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMa1XUhKSJd98JW4o9StWPrfS%3D11bPgG%2B_GDMxe25TvUY4Sugg%40mail.gmail.com).

Comment: Sounds indeed like the likely cause, on the other hand we already have planned to bring it offline sunday and do a backup restore to a new server. Think it is safer to leave it running till then. I'll try restarting it afterwards would be nice to know nothing serious was wrong.

Comment: Make sure the new server is running the latest minor release fo 9.3. Even better would be to upgrade.

Comment: Yes we switched to the latest 10.8 on a new server. Restart of postgresql on old server also fixed the issue so it was indeed the problem described in your answer.